# How to support both landscape and portrait in ONLY ONE UIView

Tags: ios, swift, device-orientation

So Im having difficulties trying to make a single UIView handle both landscape mode and portrait while the rest of the app is portrait only. I have been working on this problem for hours and all the solutions I find only apply to UIViewControllers not UIViews.

What I've tried so far consists of enabling `shouldAutorotate` to return true only if the view that I want to be able to go into landscape and portrait is present, like this:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {

        // ONLY ROTATE IF MEDIA VIEW IS PRESENT
        var boolToReturn = false

        // CHECK IF MEDIA VIEW IS PRESENT
        if self.view.subviews[self.view.subviews.count - 1] is MediaView {
            boolToReturn = true
            return boolToReturn
        }



        return boolToReturn

    }
`
```

MediaView is the UIView that I need to be viewable in portrait and landscape. MediaView's superview is my UIViewControllers view. Now this actually works; however, when my phone is rotated into landscape and MediaView is not present the status bar rotates into landscape even though the view does not auto rotate with it.

So my question is how do I completely disable landscape mode if MediaView is not present and then enable it when it is present. Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

Comment: I think you want to use a separate ViewController for the rotating view, which then always return `true` for `shouldAutoRotate`

Comment: Theres gotta be some sort of walk around for this situation! A ViewController would sort of complicate things for my case so unless its absolutely necessary, I would rather have a subclass of UIView

Comment: Surely you know if a media view is present; your code added it to the view hierarchy. When you add the view, set a Boolean that indicates it is present and use that to determine whether to return true or false

Comment: `- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window`. You can use that to tell the window to NOT rotate when a view is present and window.rootViewController is some specific viewController OR window.restorationIdentifier = some unique identifier.

Comment: @Brandon this works well! When you use the equivalent of supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow in a UIViewController it does not allow you to return multiple orientations like this method does at least in Swift 3 as far as I can tell. Thanks!